# How to get the location of the DLL currently executing?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, file-io

I have a config file that I need to load as part of the execution of a dll I am writing.

The problem I am having is that the place I put the dll and config file is not the "current location" when the app is running.

For example, I put the dll and xml file here:

> D:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins

But if I try to reference the xml file (in my dll) like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@".\AggregatorItems.xml")
```

then **.\AggregatorItems.xml** translates to:

> C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\AggregatorItems.xml

So, I need to find a way (I hope) of knowing where the dll that is currently executing is located.  Basically I am looking for this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(CoolDLLClass.CurrentDirectory+@"\AggregatorItems.xml")
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You are looking for [`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx)

```
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string xmlFileName = Path.Combine(assemblyFolder,"AggregatorItems.xml");
```

**Note:**

The `.Location` property returns the location of the currently running DLL file.

Under some conditions the DLL is shadow copied before execution, and the `.Location` property will return the path of the copy. If you want the path of the original DLL, use the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` property instead.

`.CodeBase` contains a prefix (`file:\`), which you may need to remove.

Comment: Alas!  That returns `C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\tfs\\de3c0c8e\\c1bdf790\\assembly\\dl3\\20b156cb\\22331f24_bfb9cb01\\AggregatorItems.xml`

Comment: Ah! But `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` has it!

Comment: How did you load that DLL then? I tested both with an executable and a library DLL used by another EXE and the `Location` property worked for both.

Comment: I am doing a TFS Server Side Plugin (details here: http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/10/27/devleoping-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010.aspx)  So when I put the dll in a specific folder TFS "Does its thing" and loads it up.  It is possible it copies it first.  Either way, `CodeBase` works great.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: CodeBase gave me file:\\c:\myassemblypath, which is weird

Comment: @Matt use new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath to get a real name

Comment: `string curAssemblyFolder = new System.Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;`

Answer (score 45):

Reflection is your friend, as has been pointed out. But you need to use the correct method;

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()     //gives you the entrypoint assembly for the process.
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()   // gives you the assembly from which the current method was called.
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() // gives you the assembly in which the currently executing code is defined
Assembly.GetAssembly( Type t )  // gives you the assembly in which the specified type is defined.
```

Answer (score 18):

In my case (dealing with my assemblies loaded [as file] into Outlook):

```
typeof(OneOfMyTypes).Assembly.CodeBase
```

Note the use of `CodeBase` (not `Location`) on the `Assembly`. Others have pointed out alternative methods of locating the assembly.

Answer (score 6):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: Note: for Asp.Net apps the DLL is shadow copied before execution, and the .Location property will return the path of the copy.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with an asp.net application and you want to locate assemblies when using the debugger, they are usually put into some temp directory. I wrote the this method to help with that scenario.

```
private string[] GetAssembly(string[] assemblyNames)
{
    string [] locations = new string[assemblyNames.Length];


    for (int loop = 0; loop <= assemblyNames.Length - 1; loop++)       
    {
         locations[loop] = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.IsDynamic && a.ManifestModule.Name == assemblyNames[loop]).Select(a => a.Location).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return locations;
}
```

For more details see this blog post http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2015/05/finding-the-location-of-a-running-assembly-in-net/

If you can't change the source code, or redeploy, but you can examine the running processes on the computer use Process Explorer. I written a detailed description [here](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/09/locating-and-checking-an-executing-dll-on-a-running-web-server/).

It will list all executing dlls on the system, you may need to determine the process id of your running application, but that is usually not too difficult.

I've written a full description of how do this for a dll inside IIS - http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/09/locating-and-checking-an-executing-dll-on-a-running-web-server/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(new System.Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath)
```