# How to determine what the installation path of a loaded assembly is at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I would like to create a separate log file for a C# com server dll I load into Excel. 
However, when I set up my logger I need to tell it where the `assembly.dll.config` file is. This `config` file is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company Name` but I don't know how to get this path in a dynamic way at runtime and I don't want to hard code it for obvious reasons.

I tried to use:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "assembly.dll.config"` but this just gives me Excel's install directory:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\assembly.dll.config`

Is there some way I can get the path of the dll's config file at runtime?

Comment: The Assembly type has the following static methods: GetCallingAssembly, GetEntryAssembly, GetExecutingAssembly. Is it this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, just found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764680/how-to-get-the-location-of-the-dll-currently-executing `string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);` Thanks!

Comment: Side note: assemblies normally don't have own ".config" files, so what you are trying to do is unusual and likely to be overlooked by anyone else using your system in the future.

Comment: @Alexei: Generally not true. There are quite a few software out there that allow installation of plug-ins/extensions in form of DLLs. Those DLLs have their own config files. But i don't know what the OP is shooting for... :)

Comment: The reason I want the dll to have it's own config file is that it's an in-process com server that I send data to via a socket from an add-in. So, for trouble shooting purposes, I want the add-in to have a log and also the com server to have a log just to make it easier to track down issues in this client-server setup. I'm not sure if this is best practice but it does limit log entries to one "subject" per log file (i.e. add-in or com server), which to me makes sense... :)