# Get the root directory of the EXE - C#

Tags: c#

I have the EXE in the following location:

```
C:\Projects\Bin\Sample.EXE
```

I want to get the path in C# like this:

```
C:\Projects\
```

One way to do this is:

```
string str = "C:\\Projects\\Bin\\Sample.EXE"
string res = str.Replace("Bin", "")
```

But this is NOT an efficient way. My `Bin` folder can be changed to `Bin1`, `Bin2` etc ... So the `Bin` name is NOT constant. It can be `C:\\Projects\\Debug\\Sample.EXE` also. Basically, I want to move one level up in the directory structure.

Can you please provide me sample code ?

Here is the sample code I am looking for:

@marc_s code

This is completely different from above two previous questions and I did not find solution to my issue using earlier two links.

Comment: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` Gives you the executing directory, you can then use the methods in `System.IO.Directory` to move up the chain.

Comment: To move backwards (up one level), use the `../` path.

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4764782/467473

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the location of the currently executing assembly, and go up one level from that directory - like this:

```
-- get path of the executing assembly
string currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

-- get the parent directory for that path
string parentPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentPath, ".."));
```

Comment: This is working great ! The key statement will be - Path.Combine(currentPath, "..");

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = @"C:\Projects\Bin\Sample.EXE";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

string res = file.Directory.Parent.FullName;
Console.WriteLine(res); // C:\Projects
```

Comment: I used both of them .... System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location and string path = @"C:\Projects\Bin\Sample.EXE";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

string res = file.Directory.Parent.FullName;
Console.WriteLine(res); // C:\Projects    Still I am testing ...