# Getting full path for project containing a.cs

Tags: c#

I have two C# projects `Proj1` and `Proj2`, in Visual Studio under a solution.
`Proj2` makes use of method `meth1` in `a.cs` in `Proj1`.

In `meth1`,

```
public string meth1(){
return Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
}
```

It returns the full path of `Proj2` when I am calling the method from `Proj2`. Is there a way to let it getting the path of `Proj1` regardless where the method is call?

Comment: Once your code's compiled, it's completely independent of projects and solutions. Is there a particular reason why you need the path to the project directory?

Comment: [You might want to take a look at this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764680/how-to-get-the-location-of-the-dll-currently-executing)

Comment: There will be no source codes once you deploy your application. You can do this on your machine only, therefore just hardcoding the path is good enough. Alternatively you could parse the sln file, but again this isn't going to work on client machine.

Comment: If it's suitable depending on your needs, you can also add this path as a setting in `Proj2`. That way you won't have to re-compile the application if you need to change it in future.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find Proj1.dll's location here: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Class1)).Location`, where `Class1` is the type wherein the `meth1` is defined. It can be called form outside of the Proj1.dll assembly.

If you are in the Proj1.dll, then you can use: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;`