# Assembly.LoadFrom(...) is relative from first executable

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, .net-assembly, assemblies

So I have made an updater for my application. It downloads my application (a .dll file) tp `%appdata%/Folder` and opens it via reflection like this:

```
var appdataFolder =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\[ApplicationName]\";

var mainAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(appdataFolder + @"TF2Callout.dll");
mainAssembly.GetType("TF2Callout.App").GetMethod("Main").Invoke(null, null);
```

This opens the `.dll` and executes the static void Main. But in my application I have this:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("SomeOtherDll.dll");
```

I would expect the application to search for the .dll in the `%appdata%/[application name]` folder because it is saved there, however, it tries to find the file in the folder of the installer, which is in my program files.

How would I go about fixing this? I would rather not make the `SomeOtherDll.dll` get loaded from an absolute path, because it might change.

Comment: You will have to use absolute path. The framework will search in executable folder if no specific path is mentioned. That's the default behavior.

Comment: Really no way to make it relative to the Application's dll?

Comment: You must have *some* idea where "application's dll" is stored.  Putting the "updater" executable in the same directory as the app would be a wise idea, now you can use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location

Answer (score 0):

`Assembly.LoadFrom` behaves as specified at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx :

> assemblyFile may be absolute or relative to the current directory, and
>   the assembly is loaded into the domain of the caller.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx has details about what `current directory` means.

If you wish to load from a specific location, you must use an absolute path. You may be able to construct that absolute path by using `appdataFolder` or checking the path of an existing DLL (e.g. [How to get the location of the DLL currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764680/how-to-get-the-location-of-the-dll-currently-executing) ). But fundamentally, if you want the DLL to load reliably, you need to use an absolute path.